# python 3.6 writing a list to a text file only writes last value in list into the text file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a list of variable values to a text file, but only the last variable value is actually being entered.  Making my head hurt.  I know this question and many others very much like it have already been asked, but I have yet to find my solution.

```
start = time.time()
loglist = [proc_id, order_num, sched_type, seq_action, start]
```

loglist contains the following values:
['4', '1', '1', 'SQL', 1513274129.7563317]

```
with open("c:/temp/actionlog.txt", 'a+') as op:
            writer = csv.writer(op, lineterminator='\n', delimeter='\t')
            for l in loglist:
                writer.writerow([l])
```

the output text file only contains:
11:13 AM 12/14/2017

This should be simple (and I'm sure it is) but I am at a loss.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try and run this simplified code yourself. For me it works perfectly fine (apart from `delimiter` being misspelt).

Comment: Seriously?  Just because I misspelled delimiter?  Thanks for shining a light on my problem for me.  I think I'll just spend the rest of the day hiding under my desk.

Comment: If that were the only reason, you wouldn't have any output in your file because the code would never get to writing any row. But perhaps that output was already written earlier when the code was still working (but incorrect).

Comment: woking now, but writing vertically and I need it to write tab delimited like the list.  Thanks - it's one of those days.

Comment: I suppose `loglist` is in reality a list of lists or a lists of tuples. You want the `l` in `for l in loglist` to refer to one row and then write it by just passing it to `writer.writerow` without wrapping it. Either way, will you delete this question or should I post my comment as an answer? If it stays open, people will keep looking at it unnecessarily.